# How to compare arrays with higher order functions? JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, properties, higher-order-functions

I'm trying to compare an array with a property for an assignment and I can only use higher order functions (.map(), .filter(), .forEach(), .some() etc...). The array is "userWishlist" and the properties are from the ID's in objects from the "parks" array "parks[index].id". Does anyone have any advice for solving this sort of problem? My code as of right now only returns:

```
[{"id":1,"name":"Acadia","areaInSquareKm":198.6,"location":{"state":"Maine"}}]
```

when called with:

```
getWishlistParksForUser(parks, users, "dwayne.m55")
```

Why won't my code return all of the "park" objects that match the "wishlist" array?

```js
/* Function should compare the user's wishlist with the parks */
function getWishlistParksForUser(parks, users, userID) {
  let wishArray = [];
  // Find the user
  const findUser = Object.keys(users).filter(user => user == userID);
  // Create array out of wishlist
  const userWishlist = users[findUser].wishlist.map(list => list);
  // Compare the two arrays and push park into wishlist array
  const parkID = userWishlist.forEach((wish, index) => {
    if (wish === parks[index].id) wishArray.push(parks[index])
  })

  return wishArray;
}

// The users objects (non-editable)
const users = {
  "karah.branch3": {
    visited: [2],
    wishlist: [1, 3],
  },
  "dwayne.m55": {
    visited: [2, 3],
    wishlist: [1, 3],
  },
};

// The parks array (non-editable)
const parks = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "Acadia",
    areaInSquareKm: 198.6,
    location: {
      state: "Maine"
    },
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Canyonlands",
    areaInSquareKm: 1366.2,
    location: {
      state: "Utah"
    },
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "Zion",
    areaInSquareKm: 595.9,
    location: {
      state: "Utah"
    },
  },
];

console.log(getWishlistParksForUser(parks, users, "dwayne.m55"));
```

Comment: "create array out of wishlist". It's already an array, why do you have to make it an array with `map()`?

Comment: `findUser` is just an array containing `userID`. What's the point of that? And why are you using an array as an object property? Just use `users[userID].wishlist`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's you can solve it using directly a map from the user whishList

for each whish Id you *map* to the object *searching* on the park

```js
/* Function should compare the user's wishlist with the parks */
function getWishlistParksForUser(parks, users, userID) {
  return users[userID].wishlist.map(wishId => parks.find(p => p.id == wishId));
}

// The users objects (non-editable)
const users = {
  "karah.branch3": {
    visited: [2],
    wishlist: [1, 3],
  },
  "dwayne.m55": {
    visited: [2, 3],
    wishlist: [1, 2],
  },
};

// The parks array (non-editable)
const parks = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "Acadia",
    areaInSquareKm: 198.6,
    location: {
      state: "Maine"
    },
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Canyonlands",
    areaInSquareKm: 1366.2,
    location: {
      state: "Utah"
    },
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "Zion",
    areaInSquareKm: 595.9,
    location: {
      state: "Utah"
    },
  },
];

console.log(getWishlistParksForUser(parks, users, "dwayne.m55"));
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `index` is the index of the current wishlist element, but you're using it as an index into `parks`. So you only return a park if it's at the same index in the `parks` array as its ID in the `wishlist`.

You need to use `find()` to find the park with the current wishlist ID.

```js
/* Function should compare the user's wishlist with the parks */
function getWishlistParksForUser(parks, users, userID) {
  let wishArray = [];
  const userWishlist = users[userID].wishlist;
  // Compare the two arrays and push park into wishlist array
  userWishlist.forEach((wish) => {
    let foundPark = parks.find(p => p.id == wish);
    if (foundPark) {
      wishArray.push(foundPark)
    }
  })

  return wishArray;
}

// The users objects (non-editable)
const users = {
  "karah.branch3": {
    visited: [2],
    wishlist: [1, 3],
  },
  "dwayne.m55": {
    visited: [2, 3],
    wishlist: [1, 3],
  },
};

// The parks array (non-editable)
const parks = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "Acadia",
    areaInSquareKm: 198.6,
    location: {
      state: "Maine"
    },
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Canyonlands",
    areaInSquareKm: 1366.2,
    location: {
      state: "Utah"
    },
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "Zion",
    areaInSquareKm: 595.9,
    location: {
      state: "Utah"
    },
  },
];

console.log(getWishlistParksForUser(parks, users, "dwayne.m55"));
```

Answer (score 0):

there're two problems in your code,

1. `const findUser = Object.keys(users).filter(user => user == userID);` no need to do this ,as you could just use user[userId] to get specific user as user is an object like a map.
2. `const selectedItem = parks.find(item => item.id === wish)`  you need another search method to get right parkitem for you,just get part item with same index of userWishlist will not do the trick.

i have modified your code, please try this

```
/* Function should compare the user's wishlist with the parks 

*/
function getWishlistParksForUser(parks, users, userID) {
  let wishArray = [];
  // Find the user
//   const findUser = Object.keys(users).filter(user => user == userID);
  // Create array out of wishlist
  const userWishlist = users[userID].wishlist.map(list => list);
  // Compare the two arrays and push park into wishlist array
  const parkID = userWishlist.forEach((wish, index) => {
    const selectedItem = parks.find(item => item.id === wish)
    if (selectedItem) wishArray.push(selectedItem)
  })

  return wishArray;
}

// The users objects (non-editable)
const users = {
  "karah.branch3": {
    visited: [2],
    wishlist: [1, 3],
  },
  "dwayne.m55": {
    visited: [2, 3],
    wishlist: [1, 3],
  },
};

// The parks array (non-editable)
const parks = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "Acadia",
    areaInSquareKm: 198.6,
    location: {
      state: "Maine"
    },
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Canyonlands",
    areaInSquareKm: 1366.2,
    location: {
      state: "Utah"
    },
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "Zion",
    areaInSquareKm: 595.9,
    location: {
      state: "Utah"
    },
  },
];

console.log(getWishlistParksForUser(parks, users, "dwayne.m55"));
```